# What type should be pointed to for the result of cuDeviceGetGraphMemAttribute()?

Tags: memory-management, cuda, type-erasure, cuda-driver, cuda-graphs

`cuDeviceGetGraphMemAttribute()` takes a void pointer to a result variable. But - what type does it expect the pointed-to value to be? The documentation (for CUDA v12.0) [doesn't say](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-driver-api/group__CUDA__GRAPH.html#group__CUDA__GRAPH_1g359903c2447ac22b4e1a0dce26adfef5). I'm guessing it's an unsigned 64-bit type, but I want to make sure.

Comment: 64-bit unsigned, https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__TYPES.html#group__CUDART__TYPES_1g4764cb94cff3171bdc738dd11a4c2ba6

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For [all current attributes](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-runtime-api/group__CUDART__TYPES.html#group__CUDART__TYPES_1g4764cb94cff3171bdc738dd11a4c2ba6) you can get with this function, the `void *` must point to a `cuuint64_t`.

<sub>Thanks goes to @AbatorAbeter for pointing out where this is stated.</sub>